# How to delete some million rows in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my system, a lot of data has accumulated in a table. Now I don't understand how to delete them.  Then I realized that I need to use partitions, but I can't go back in time.
Today i have 10 million rows, need to delete 8 million rows.

For table created indexes. PK is column with uuidv4.

I wrote PostgreSQL Procudere to delete rows in loop. Every loop iteration i delete 1000 rows and set commit. But this procedure increases the load on the database by several times the normal load. In the end I deleted 2000 rows in 1 hour.

I then try to delete 100 rows using a simple SQL script with begin-commit, but I get a high load.
In 15 minutes I deleted those measly 100 rows.

Any ideas or exprience with this problem?)

Comment: Deletes can be expensive, it's just a fact of life, especially on tables with heavy, on-going write activity. If you're deleting *most* of the data you may consider creating a new table with the selected records you need, then trying to switch over. It's also possible in some situations to create a new, empty table and start populating that, then migrate over the records you need.

Comment: I would create a new database/table with the exact same structure and `SELECT INTO` it --  That way you're only dealing with 2 million rows .. Not 8 million.  Lesser of two evils I am afraid.

Comment: Impossible to answer since we don't know how to find the records to be deleted, nor the indexes, nor the locks, etc. etc. But 10 million rows is imho not a lot of data. Deleting 2000 records in one hour is also hard to understand, most systems running on decent hardware can do this per second.

Comment: I didn't even think about the serious time you're talking about ..  You should be able to delete 8M rows even with complicated keys in < 2 hours.  You have either an inefficient SQL call (Too many joins including all fields etc) or you're seriously underpowered.

Comment: Without the procedure code, Postgres version,hardware specifications and table definition this is basically unanswerable. **Add this information as text update to question**.

Comment: @Zak Does "Too many joins" even exists? You can destroy performance with and without joins, independent on the number of joins. Databases like PostgreSQL are highly optimized to work with joins. Usually the problem sits behind the keyboard... :)

Comment: This smacks of missing indexes on foreign keys.  Then for every row deleted it will need to full scan all the referring tables to make sure they don't violate the constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be quick. Hard to believe that it's taking an hour to delete 2k records.

Here are some possible cases:

- Delete triggers auto-vacuum and auto-vacuum process is resource incentive.
- Your application using data and acquiring locks which adds delay in deletion.

I would suggest create new table with partition and copy the require data to new table and run following command to alter the table.

```
ALTER TABLE example_table RENAME TO example_table_old;

ALTER TABLE new_table RENAME TO example_table;
```

Drop the `example_table_old` after successful migration.

Comment: Only drop the `old` table when you are **sure** everything is working OK.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to delete all constraints applied to the table, and then try to delete the data. After deletion, you can return all all constraints that have been deleted.

Another option is to create a temporary table with the same structure as the table has (do not include constraints), copy the data you want to keep into this table, delete the old one, rename the new one with the name of the old one, and restore constraints.